# Which subsets of R are both compact and connect? Justify your answer.

Tags: real-analysis

Which subsets of R are **both** compact and connected? Justify your answer.

Does one example seem to suffice for what this question is asking? And, if so I was thinking [4,6) ∪ (5,9] as it is both compact and connected.  The interval is closed and bounded, so it is compact, and no separation in the interval, so it is connected.

Please see what you think with my thoughts as I am not exactly sure I have done it correctly.

Comment: For your example, it is equivalent to [4,9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example would be any closed interval, e.g. [0,1].

In general, any closed interval [a,b] would fit your requirements.